# Jquery toggle (visible/invisible) for only the item clicked on in a template-generated html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates, html-rendering

**Code**

```
  <ul>
    {% for item in lis %}
    <li>
      <div id="single-toggle">|Toggle|</div>
      <div class="visible-when-folded">
        <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>
        <div class="date">{{ item.date }}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="invisible-when-folded">
        <div class="about">{{ item.about }}</div>
        <div class="contact_info">{{ item.contact_info }}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

**Example output code**

- |Toggle|
            
              Peter
              24-04-1990
            

            
              A friendly guy
              0474657434
- |Toggle|
            
              Martha
              22-02-1984
            

            
              An amazing gal
              0478695675
- |Toggle|
            
              William
              12-11-1974
            

            
              An oldie
              0478995675

**Desired behavior**

I would like that whenever you click on `|Toggle|` the `about`(e.g. `A friendly guy`)
 and `contact_info`(e.g. `0474657434`) part dissapear/reappear.

**Attempt at solution**

```
$(function(){
  $("#single-toggle").click(
    function(){ $("div.invisible-when-folded").toggle(); } );
});
```

But unfortunately this toggles the fields for each item in the list as opposed to only the one I click on.

### Edit

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def toggle(request):
    lis = [{'name':'Peter', 'date':'24-04-1990', 'about':'A friendly guy',
            'contact_info':'0474657434' }, 
          {'name':'Martha', 'date':'22-02-1984', 'about':'An amazing gal', 
            'contact_info':'0478695675' },
          {'name':'William', 'date':'12-11-1974', 'about':'An oldie', 
            'contact_info':'0478995675' }]

    return render_to_response('page.html', {'lis':lis},
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Using the same id for a repeated element is not a good idea. Change your #single-toggle to a class and use it.

Comment: I would normally never do this, but used it with the vain hope that it would respond differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the current object as [context in the selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get the element related to event source object. You also need to use `class instead of id` or **generate unique ids** for div with id = single-toggle as html elements are `supposed` to have unique ids.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8PjuF/1/)**

I have give the div with id a class="single-toggle"

Change

```
$("div.invisible-when-folded").toggle();
```

To

```
$("div.invisible-when-folded", this).toggle();
```

You code

```
$(function(){
  $("#single-toggle").click(
    function(){ $("div.invisible-when-folded", this).toggle(); } );
});
```

Comment: When I add `this` the toggle just doesn't respond anymore.

Comment: I have updated me answer with live demo and explained one more flaw in the code.

Comment: Still does not work with changing the id to class. Your demo is not fully representative for my case because I am using a templating language (such as the `Django templating language` or `Jinja2`). Also, why do you repeatedly use `ul`?

Comment: IMO the thing that matter is generated html whatever language we use. I mistakenly used ul repeadly your ur repeating li I change in domo check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8PjuF/1/ please show use generated html

Comment: I'm happy you showed me the demo but unfortunately this does not solve the problem.
I edited the original post so you can see an example of the function in my views of my django project that generates the html output.

Comment: It wasn't because of the templating language, I must've implemented it wrong before. Anyone else having this problem can find alternative solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222743/toggling-elements-with-identical-class-names-visible-invisible-for-only-those-cl/14222808).

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus the function on the `div` within the clicked `div`... The actual code you need to use is:

```
$(function(){
  $("#single-toggle").click(
    function(){ $("div.invisible-when-folded", this).toggle(); } );
});
```