# Toggling elements with identical class names visible/invisible for only those clicked on

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="single-toggle">|Toggle|</div>
    <div class="visible-when-folded">
      <div class="name">Peter</div>
      <div class="date">3 january 1984</div>
    </div>
    <div class="invisible-when-folded">
      <div class="about">Funny guy</div>
      <div class="contact_info">0879876745</div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="single-toggle">|Toggle|</div>
    <div class="visible-when-folded">
      <div class="name">David</div>
      <div class="date">17 April 1988</div>
    </div>
    <div class="invisible-when-folded">
      <div class="about">Jackass</div>
      <div class="contact_info">0979876345</div>
    </div>    
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Desired result**

That when I click on the `|Toggle|` element only the elements inside `div.invisible-when-folded` disappear in the respective `li` element.

**What I have tried**

Clicking on `|Toggle|` in [this code](http://jsbin.com/urodit/178/edit) toggles the div invisible/visible from both `li` elements at the same time. How do I let it toggle only the `li` of the toggle I clicked in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all (following) siblings of the clicked element with that class:

```
$(this).nextAll('.invisible-when-folded').toggle();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/urodit/181/edit)

Have a look at jQuery's [traversal methods.](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: +1 for realising (and admitting) you read the question too fast and +1-ing the person who told you so.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$(".single-toggle").click(function(){ 
  $(this).closest('li').find('.invisible-when-folded').toggle(); 
});
```